# How can I use a secure file in a CircleCI build?

Tags: maven, maven-3, circleci

I am trying to build a project on CircleCI that needs access to a secure file. I cannot use an environment variable, it must be in the form of a file. In my case it is specifically a Maven `settings.xml` file, but there are other use cases. What can I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are actually quite a few solutions to this problem:

**File as Environment Variable**

If the contents of the file are short (just a password for example), you can store the entire file as an environment variable, and then add a line like this to your circle.yaml build file:

```
echo $SECURE_FILE > mySecureFile
```

**Variable Substitution**

If the contents of the file are large, but only a small portion of the file is secure, you can store the file in your code repository, and then use sed to replace a fixed string with an environment variable, like this:

```
sed -e s/SECURE_PASSWORD/${SECURE_PASSWORD}/g mySecureFile.tmpl > mySecureFile
```

**Encrypt the File**

You can encrypt your config file and check it into your source repository, then store the decryption key as an environment variable. Decrypt it during the build process.

**Maven Settings.xml Special Case**

For the special case of Maven settings.xml files, you can use environment variables in your settings.xml, so you can do something like this:

- Store your settings.xml in conf/settings.xml
- Replace any secure text with something like this: `${env.MY_SECURE_TEXT}`
- Set `MY_SECURE_TEXT` in the circle CI configuration
- In circle.yaml, add '-s
  conf/settings.xml' to your Maven build commands.